# Calendar Plugin for Check in and Check Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, datepicker

Does anyone know a muli-calendar plugin similar to this site? or how can i tweek bootstrap datepicker to look like something similar to this site?

https://hansarhotels.windsurfercrs.com/ibe/index.aspx?hotelID=14234&langID=1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)

It also uses the bootstrap framework